# RMarkdown read csv

Tags: r, csv, r-markdown

I am getting an error using this code in an RMarkdown document:

```
library(RCurl)

read.csv.orig = read.csv

read.csv = function(file, ...) {
  if (is.character(file)) {
    if (grepl('^http://', file)) {
      data = getURL(file, ssl.verifypeer=0L, followlocation=1L)
      return (read.csv.orig(text=data, ...))  
    } else if (grepl('^http://', file)) {
      data = getURL(file)
      return (read.csv.orig(text=data, ...)) 
    } else {
      return (read.csv.orig(file, ...))
    }
  } else {
    return (read.csv.orig(file, ...))
  }
}
```

Actually I've tried it directly on R and it works as expected, while it shows this message if I try to compile the document via the `makefile.r` :

```
Error in read.csv.orig(text = data, ...) : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> read.csv -> read.csv.orig

Execution halted
```

Could you please help me to figure out what is going wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: We need more information to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this problem. You've included the function definition, but what code did you call it with? What is `makefile.r`? On a side note, are you aware that `read.csv` already supports URLs? You shouldn't need any of this wrapper code in practice.

Comment: Dear @JoeRoe, thank you.
Actually this problem is confined in some outputs (e.g. pdf and docx), while the html compiles well.
The code worked 1 year ago without hassle, so I don't understand where is the problem: could it be maybe the pandoc part?

Comment: Well, it seems actually a problem in pandoc with the pangloss filter. I will check it later, but it does not seem to be related to RMarkdown itself. Many thanks!